# Window refresh missing after replacing DataContext

Tags: wpf

My application has two tabs in a TabControl.

I have (model) class (implementing INotifyPropertyChanged) bound to a the controls in the first tab via DataConext. Data binding works fine. I then replace the instance assigned to the DataContext with a new instance. Then the new values are not shown. As soon as I switch to the second tab and back the values are visible. It appears as if the data binding need some kind of kick ass to start working.

How could I force the view to re-bind programmatically?

Comment: Is your Model also bound using a Property of an INotifyPropertyChanged object ?

Comment: Can you share some code?

Comment: @Aron you should post this on nearly every question regarding a UI-Issue . 
I always edit questions where i remove peoples margins and stuff .

Comment: please post it ... 
Are you raising PropertyChanged on that property when you change it ..?